# Middleman sitemap resources select - query on locale

Tags: ruby, middleman

I want to interrogate the SiteMap - getting a list of Tasks from each page - unfortunately as this is a internationalised site it comes in a few languages

As such the below repeats the tasks for each language in the system.

```
- sitemap.resources.select { | r | r.data.todo.present? }.each do | data |

    = data.request_path
```

Basically I want to get the Sitemap for one locale only - but do not know the syntax for this

Any help appreciated

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Hiya I dont think I did - I think I reverted to using blog.

Answer (score 2):

I came across https://forum.middlemanapp.com/t/querying-proxy-pages-by-locals/1195. You can filter pages that match the current locale with the following:

```
sitemap.resources.select do |r|
  r.metadata[:options][:lang] == I18n.locale &&
  r.data.todo.present?
end
```

Or if you need to loop through all locales you can use the following:

```
(langs).each do |locale|
  sitemap.resources.select do |r|
    r.metadata[:options][:lang] == locale &&
    r.data.todo.present?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [middleman-blog](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/blogging/) to store, classify and access your pages.

This would allow you to conveniently filter your pages. Untested example:

```
- blog.articles.select { | a | a.data.todo.present? && a.lang == I18n.locale }.each do | article |

  = article.request_path
```

The middleman-blog extension allows defining multiple blogs. This allows to use it as a makeshift database adapter: blogs are DB tables and posts are DB items.

Consider this (`config.rb`):

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.name = 'dev_en'
  blog.sources = "blogs/development/{year}-{month}-{day}-{title}.html"
  blog.permalink = "devblog/{title}.html"
  blog.layout = :blog_article
end

activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.name = 'dev_ru'
  blog.sources = "ru/blogs/development/{year}-{month}-{day}-{title}.html"
  blog.permalink = "ru/devblog/{title}.html"
  blog.layout = :blog_article
end
```

I defined two blogs for different languages. And i can access each like this:

```
- blog('dev_en').articles.select { | a | a.data.todo.present? }.each do | article |

  = article.request_path
```

Comment: I would prefer to access the task I need to do through the Sitemap.

Comment: I tried to find a Sitemap solution for you first but the Sitemap Resource does not seem to provide locale data.